# How to select a data from a table using the where and like statement and echo it

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause, sql-like

I am having a issue on how to select a data from a database table using the were and like statement.

```
$hy=mysql_query("select  (Total) AS firstterm 
                 FROM studentmark, subject 
                 where studentmark.student_id='$name' 
                   AND studentmark.YEAR='$ya' 
                   AND subject.code=studentmark.code    
                   AND studentmark.TERM='$term' LIKE 'F%'");

$hm=mysql_num_rows($hy);
$fetch=mysql_fetch_array($hy);

echo $fetch['firstterm'];
```

the issue is that the LIKE 'F%' (FIRST) in the term which has 89 as Total was not selected in the table but the LIKE 'S%'  (SECOND) in the term which has 73 was selected. is there anything i am missing?

the table below

```
TERM   | CODE |student_id|contAss20Asg|ClassWk10 |Test2nd10|YEAR |EXAM| TOTAL
FIRST  | AGR  | John     |  18        |5         |   7     |2011 | 59 |   89
SECOND |AGR2  |John      |  13        |6         |   4     |2011 | 40 |   73
THIRD  |AGR3  |John      |  18        |6         |   8     |2011 | 34 |   64
FIRST  |BIO   |John      |  12        |3         |   3     |2011 | 55 |   73
SECOND |BIO2  |John      |  14        |8         |   7     |2011 | 56 |   85
THIRD  |BIO3  |John      |  12        |8         |   8     |2011 | 42 |   70
```

My code is stated below

```
<?php echo '</td><td>'?>
  <?php 
    if ($fetch['Total']==NULL){
echo 'missed';
}else 
    $hy=mysql_query("select  (Total) AS secondterm FROM studentmark, subject where studentmark.student_id='$name' AND studentmark.YEAR='$ya' AND subject.code=studentmark.code    AND studentmark.TERM='$term' LIKE 'S%'");
$hm=mysql_num_rows($hy);
$fetch=mysql_fetch_array($hy);
echo $fetch['secondterm'];
?>
<?php echo '</td><td>'?>
  <?php 
    if ($fetch['Total']==NULL){

}else 
    $hy=mysql_query("select  (Total) AS firstterm FROM studentmark, subject where studentmark.student_id='$name' AND studentmark.YEAR='$ya' AND subject.code=studentmark.code    AND studentmark.TERM='$term' LIKE 'F%'");
$hm=mysql_num_rows($hx);

$hm=mysql_num_rows($hy);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($hy);
echo $row['secondterm'];


?>

<?php echo '</td><td>'?>
  <?php 
    if ($fetch['Total']==NULL){
//echo 'missed';
}else 
    $hy=mysql_query("select  (Total) AS thirdterm FROM studentmark, subject where studentmark.student_id='$name' AND studentmark.YEAR='$ya' AND subject.code=studentmark.code    AND studentmark.TERM='$term'");
$hm=mysql_num_rows($hy);

$hm=mysql_num_rows($hy);
$fetch=mysql_fetch_array($hy);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($hy);

echo $fetch['firstterm']+ $row['secondterm'] + $fetch['thirdterm'];

?>
```

Comment: Any feedback on any of these answers? Or are you just going to eat and run?

Answer (score 0):

LIKE is an operator for comparison, you need to use it as an operator like you would with '=','>' etc.

```
studentmark.TERM LIKE '%someval%';
```

Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The like syntax was wrong so try this

```
SELECT TOTAL AS firstterm 
FROM studentmark, subject 
WHERE studentmark.student_id='$name' 
  AND subject.code=studentmark.code   
  AND studentmark.YEAR='$ya' 
  AND studentmark.TERM LIKE 'F%'");
```

It would be better coded using the JOIN syntax as well so like this

```
SELECT TOTAL AS firstterm 
FROM studentmark
   JOIN subject ON subject.code=studentmark.code
WHERE studentmark.student_id='$name' 
  AND studentmark.YEAR='$ya' 
  AND studentmark.TERM LIKE 'F%'");
```

Also what would happen if they invented a `FOURTH` term this would not produce the correct response. As you TERM column seems to be formalised into `FIRST`, `SECOND`, `THIRD` it woudl be better to loose the LIKE completely and do

```
SELECT TOTAL AS firstterm 
FROM studentmark
   JOIN subject ON subject.code=studentmark.code
WHERE studentmark.student_id='$name' 
  AND studentmark.YEAR='$ya' 
  AND studentmark.TERM = 'FIRST'");
```